# Check if service is from Microsoft

Tags: c++, winapi

How would I determine if a service is from Microsoft or not? Similar to how msconfig does.

Been looking through the service APIs and I can't find anything.

**EDIT:**
For clarification, I'm talking about Windows Services (Windows Update, Windows Search, Computer Browser, etc)

Comment: Are you asking about Windows Services or WCF or Soap Web Service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check if the service's executable is signed by Microsoft.